# Problem with log4j2.properties configuration file in Spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

```
property.filename = logs

appenders = console, file
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/propertieslogs.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

loggers=file
logger.file.name=in.nit.service.CarService
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
logger.file.additivity = false

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

The problem is that logs are generated only for one class at a time when i use
`logger.file.name=in.nit.service.CarService`

how to read all classes logs at a time in spring boot project  into to a single log file????

And can anyone explain meaning of each property in logging and rootLogger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify root package name in place of class name.

Suppose, your application root package name is `in.nit`, then logger configuration will look like below -

```
loggers=file
logger.file.name=in.nit
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
logger.file.additivity = false
```